# mysql и module.exports в NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, export

Хэллоу IT World )

При изучении NodeJS столкнулся со сложностью объединения решений

В начале главного файла (app.js) объявляем require('mysql'), далее объявляем подключение к ней (pool, poolLog), далее из блоков app.get нужно все функции разместить в отдельных файлах, и вот тут проблема - в каждом файле нужно объявлять pool, и ? Есть ли структура какая то, для примера, что бы можно было самому изучить как по феншую структурировать проект? Решения по отдельности работают все, но собрать какой то скилет не получается

сам остановился на таком:

```
// *** app.js *** //

//модули
.. много модулей ..
var mysql = require('mysql');

//пул
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 1,
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '123',
    database : 'MyDB'
});

var methodsHow = require('./tools/how');
var methodsNow = require('./tools/now');

app.get('/howmutch',function(req, res){
    res.send("count: "+methodsNow.howmutch()+"");
});

app.get('/hownow',function(req, res){
    res.send("now: "+methodsHow.hownow()+"");
});

app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.send("welcome");
});


// *** /tools/how.js *** //

//т.к. пул и mysql не видны, объявлены 2й раз
var pool = require('mysql').createPool({
    connectionLimit : 1,
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '123',
    database : 'MyDB'
});

module.exports={
    howmutch:function(){
        var funcAnswer = -1;
        var mySqlQuery = "SHOW TABLES";
        pool.query(mySqlQuery, function(error, rows){
            if(!error){
                funcAnswer = 0;
                if(rows.length>0){
                    funcAnswer = rows.length;
                }
            }
            return funcAnswer;
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

в файле app.js вместо

```
var methodsHow = require('./tools/how');
```

пишете

```
var methodsHow = require('./tools/how').init(pool);
```

ну и в файле /tools/how.js у вас доолжно быть примерно это:

```
module.exports = {
    init: function(pool) {
        return {
            howmutch: function() {
                //тут ваша функция
            }
        }
    }
};
```